# How quickly does netstat capture network snapshot?

Tags: networking, tcp, netstat

I have a machine where there are a large number of connects and disconnects every second(or even lesser).
I need to capture the network snapshot at one instance of time. But I see that netstat takes some time to return the result by then a lot of sockets would get reconnected.

How does netstat actually work? And how quickly can it get a network snaphot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netstat gathers info from /proc/net/tcp|udp|raw files,you could capture these files quickly and parse/re-format later

strace clearly shows the same

```
$ strace -e open -f netstat -an 2>&1 |grep -v ENOENT |grep '^open("/proc'
open("/proc/net/tcp", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/proc/net/tcp6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/proc/net/udp", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/proc/net/raw", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/proc/net/raw6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/proc/net/unix", O_RDONLY)        = 3
```